# Form border creates space around inner elements

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I'm trying to create a simple bordered form that has a button and input of type="text" inside of it.

There is this spacing that appears that I cannot remove.

[image]

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
main form {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
main form .btndep {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
main form input {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form class="deposit">
        <button class="btndep">Deposit</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="0.00€">
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: Is the page zoomed-in ?

Comment: yes only for  screenshot purposes and my bad eyesight; the space remains even if its not zoomed-in @ZohirSalak

Comment: In that case i can only reproduce the problem when i zoom-in  the page, which is a common problem with zooming in chrome, i can't reproduce it in Firefox, i would say not to concern yourself with it, But if you'd like to ease your mind, you can apply a background on the form with the same dimensions as the button which a whole thing in itself

Comment: I tried zoomed out too but it remains, issue doesn't appear in firefox @ZohirSalak

Comment: It is just chrome and it's bad management of sub pixels, But you say that the issue persist even without zoom which I can't reproduce, unless there's some transformation up in your elements tree chain. However until someone else is able to reproduce the issue, you won't be having much luck

Comment: I see, thank you for trying to help @ZohirSalak ♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way around it; it seems... outline instead of border